# Create a unique list of tuple in a series sorted by order and taken randomly in a range

Tags: python, random

I'm looking for a solution to find unique lists of tuple with 6 values in a serie sorted by order and taken randomly in a range. I need to test each possible combination possible knowing that the values in each tuples must be sorted: I want to remove all tuples which have a value bigger than the next one as (10,1,2,3,4,5) and here to keep only (1,2,3,4,5,10).

i.e: output search [(0,1,2,3,4,5),(0,1,2,3,4,6),....(95,96,97,98,99,100)]

And I got a memory issue: MemoryError.

if someone as a solution, please.
Thanks in advance.
Regards

Here is my code:

```
import random
import itertools
from itertools import combinations, permutations
from random import choice, sample
score_found = list(range(math.ceil(0), math.floor(101)) # the range between score should be found
score number_number = 6 # number of risk classes
list_of_random_score=[]
for i in combinations(score_found, score_number):
    list_of_random_score.append(i) 
list_of_random_score.sort()     #sort each tuple in the list
list_of_random_score2 = list(set(list_of_random_score)) #edit the list in order to have only [(0,1,2,3,4,5),(0,1,2,3,4,6),....(95,96,97,98,99,100)].
```

Comment: 100C6 should be 1192052400?

Comment: yes, sorry my first range tested was from 0 to 90

Comment: `itertools.combinations` generate all possible outcomes. You want to sample some of them?

Comment: I wanted all of them if possible knowing that each element of the tuple should be greater than the previous one as a risk classes could not have a lower score than its previous one.

Comment: If written in C, 7GB memory is fine to store 100C6 6-byte tuple. But in Python, 32GB is still not enough. Probably there is another way to reach the goal. However, I am still confused probably because the code is partial. Try smaller number, say, 30C6 first?

Comment: In fact my goal is quite more complicated but I could not put all the code here as it is far too long. I try to find a score function based on 5 or 6 criteria with for each of them a score between 0 and 100 for a given population ranked in 6 different classes by a genetic algorithm. The GA gives an optimal weight for each criteria in order to have the best function to replicate observations with a model but currently I choose directly the division of the score scale for the 6 different classes.

Comment: My purpose is to have the weight of each criteria and the scale division which minimize the difference between a score model for a given scale to a population ranked in 6 different classes. So I want to test all possible combination of scale division for each possible weight combination